# limit 0 times infinity, rewrite to find the limit

Tags: limits

I need some help with: $\lim_{x\to 0+} x^3\cdot e^{1/x}$. How to start?

I've tried substitution $(y=1/x)$ without any luck.

I would prefer not to use L'Hopitals rule and apologizes for a bad title line.

Comment: Try writing this as $\frac{e^{1/x}}{(1/x)^3}$ and then using L'Hopitals rule

Comment: I forgott to write that I prefer not to use L'Hopitals rule. It should be possible without it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can carry on with your substitution. In the case $y = 1/x$, then as $x \to 0^+$, $y \to \infty$, and you want to look at the limit of
$$
\lim_{y\to\infty} (1/y^3) e^y = \lim_{y\to\infty} \frac{e^y}{y^3}.
$$

If you know, for instance, that the exponential grows faster than any polynomial, you can avoid L'Hopital's rule.

Answer (score 1):

Substitute $x=\frac1t$. Then this is the same as $$\lim_{t\to+\infty}\frac{e^t}{t^3}$$
Using the wellknown inequality $e^x\ge 1+x$, we have $e^t=(e^{t/4})^4\ge (1+\frac t4)^4$, so for $t>0$
$$ \frac{e^t}{t^3}\ge\frac{(1+\frac t4)^4}{t^3}>\frac1{256}t.$$

(In short: Exponential always wins over polynomial)

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $e^{1/x} > \dfrac{1}{4!x^4}$.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it...

Comment: $e^t=1+t+\dfrac{t^2}{2!}+\dfrac{t^3}{3!}+\dfrac{t^4}{4!}+\ldots$